# ActionBar inside a Layout

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Its possible that a layout contain a actionbar?

Or change the width of the actionbar?

For this part of my application i dont need a fragmentactivity, so this is a simple activity

Sorry by my English..

Green: Layouts

Red:Actionbar

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If You want that your actionbar appears in some part of screen you should use Customlayout with the use of "Include Other Layout Option"   in your screen..

or If you want to customize your actionbar, You Can Use Custom Actionbar.

http://javatechig.com/android/actionbar-with-custom-view-example-in-android

Comment: I dont understand the first part of your message

Comment: create one layout and add it to your home layout..
follow this link to know more about that...
[Include other layout](http://javatechig.com/android/android-include-tag-layout-example)